# Split() not showing when index param is used

Tags: jquery, split

I have this:

```js
$('li').click(function() { 
    var currentSrc = $('img', this).attr('src').toString();
    var grabAlt = $('img', this).attr('alt').split('|');
    //alert(grabAlt[0]);
    $('.imgSample img').attr('src', currentSrc);
    $('.projectDescription').html('<p class="projectDescription">' + grabAlt[0].join('</p>')); 
    $('.projectTitle').html(grabAlt[1]); 
});
```

When I remove the [0] and [1] I can alert either and what I'm thinking is the first value [0], does replace the project description, but trying to place each in the respective place doesn't work at all.

snippet of relevant html:

```
<section class="workArea">
    <div class="imgSample"><img src="images/samples/testImage2.png" alt="This first part will be a short description. | this second part will be the title."></div>
    <p class="projectDescription">This is to be replaced when an image is clicked on.</p>
    <h3 class="projectTitle">To be replaced</h3>
</section>
</div>

<nav>
    <ul class="print">
        <li class="liRounded"><img width="50" height="50" src="images/samples/image1.png" alt="Should replace the content in the paragraph. | Replace title copy."></li>

        <li class="liRounded"><img width="50" height="50" src="images/samples/image2.png" alt="Second. | Replace title 2."></li>

        <li class="liRounded"><img width="50" height="50" src="images/samples/image3.png" alt="third. | Replace title 3."></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Is it my syntax or usage that is wrong here?

Comment: What do you believe `grabAlt[0].join('</p>')` does?

Comment: I believe it takes the first part of the alt text (all text to the left of the piping symbol) and put it into the first value of the array. I'm creating a new paragraph, adding the content and closing the tag.

Comment: I also tried setting a variable to the alt text, then overwriting that variable with the .split as some javascript books mention but I'm just not able to split my alt text into two parts and place each piece separately.

Comment: O.K. but it doesn't do that... :)

Comment: as in, it's not working or you have other information on what grabAlt[0].join('</p>') is supposed to do?

Comment: Give me a DEMO to work with at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there, but not quite:

```
$('li').click(function() { 

    var img = $('img', this).get(0);
    var src = img.src;  // no need for .attr
    var alt = img.alt;  //     ditto

    var grabAlt = alt.split('|');

    $('.imgSample img').attr('src', currentSrc);
    $('.projectDescription').text(grabAlt[0]);
    $('.projectTitle').text(grabAlt[1]); 
});
```

Mostly, you don't need to put a new `<p>` inside the `.projectDescription` element, you just needed to change its text contents.

As [@gdoron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601179/gdoron) alluded to, `.join()` doesn't do what you appear to think it does - it takes an *array* of strings, and joins them together with the given separator.  It *doesn't* concatenate `grabAlt[0]` with `</p>`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for that insight. I see how this works now because when I did this in the past setting the text to individual li's, I was taking it all, not an index and in this case, I needed the index. Thanks again.